# as3 removing flv playing class I can still hear sound

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, flv, removechild

I have a class that adds an flv and loops it. I add it to the display object as a movieclip.

When I do a

```
removeChild(myFlv);
myFlv = null;
```

I can still hear the sound. What do I need to do to kil the sound?

Answer (score 0):

```
myFlv.stop();
removeChild(myFlv);
myFlv = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried you method thanks for your answer but had to kill the net stream and net connection - it was actually the netstream.

```
public var video:Video = new Video(1200, 800);
private var nc:NetConnection;
private var ns:NetStream;


public function die():void {
removeChild(video);
nc.close();
ns.close();

}
```